# Editing a TextField in preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to add a `TextField` in SwiftUI. It successfully appears with the initial text, but it is not editable in the preview display, only when I run a simulator. Any ideas?

```
@State var smth: String = "smth"
    
    var body: some View {
        //Not editable in preview
        TextField("Number", text: $smth)
    }
```

Comment: Your code is fine -- make sure you've pressed the play button (looks like an arrow) above the preview to switch to an active preview mode, at which time the field will be editable.

Comment: The keyboard won't show up on previews, but the text field should still work if you turn on live previews, like @jnpdx said. Just click in it and start typing, the text will show up without the keyboard.

Comment: There has been an Xcode bug in the past were live preview TextField input was broken. Seems to be back :(. I just experienced the same on 13.2.1. running the preview on iOS 15.2. switching to an iOS 14.3 simulator seems to fix it in my case. (wait for the `Preparing iPhone Simulator for Previews` to finish). https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681571

Comment: @DanielMarx Thank you for the help. It does run in the simulator, but not in the canvas preview. I remembered to press the play button above the preview simulator per a suggestion, and still am unable to edit it... The simulator will have to do!

Comment: Just to be sure: You tried changing the target simulator to an older version e.g. 14.3? Cause I'm aware you were talking about the Canvas and changing the target simulator will also affect the Canvas settings. Otherwise sorry it didn't fix it for you

Comment: Ah forgot to change the target simulator—now it allows me to type in the canvas! Sucks that this workaround has to be used... it'll have to do for now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since the comment was a legit answer I just copy paste it here. Glad it worked for you as well*

There has been an Xcode bug in the past were live preview TextField input was broken. Seems to be back :(. I just experienced the same on 13.2.1. running the preview on iOS 15.2. switching to an iOS 14.3 simulator seems to fix it in my case. (wait for the *Preparing iPhone Simulator for Previews* to finish). [Related to](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681571)

Answer (score 0):

I just download Xcode 13.3.1, and MacOs 12.4 Beta, and now I can use the physical keyboard for enter data in a TextField on a preview.I don't know if   you can download only Xcode 13.3.1 without downloading the MacOs 12.4 Beta, or  if Xcode 13.3.1 download alone resolve the problem.